# No wifi on dell inspiron 3543

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.05 alongside Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 3543 laptop. Installation was successful, but could not get the WiFi connected to the internet.

I can see my SSID being displayed on the drop down menu, but WiFi doesn't work after I click it and enter the WiFi password. The WiFi icon is displayed with an "empty WiFi" sign.

[Here is the output from running the Wireless Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23846330/)

How can I fix this so that I can access the internet?

I followed instruction from the duplicate page step by step and still have the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16.06. Which version have you installed?

Comment: Sorry the version is 16.04 LTS. Thanks

Comment: Hi Pilot6 , This is the output of lspci -knn |  grep Net  -A2          06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
 Kernel modules: bcma

Comment: Did the instructions given in answers to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) not enable you to solve this? If not, please [edit] with additional information. I could be mistaken, but it looks to me from the information you've provided like that ought to work.

Comment: I followed instructions from that page step by step , still the problem is not solved.

Comment: You need to describe what you did in details, and what happened. Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: And also run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` now and post the output.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I followed those 3 step instructions from this page  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Hi Pilot6, the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2                                                                   06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
 Kernel modules: bcma

Comment: Yes , secure boot disabled even before installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

I have Dell Inspiron 3543 as well.

Connect to the internet with a cable or connect to a Wi-Fi network with your smart-phone and tether the connection over a usb cable.

Run `sudo apt update` if you haven't already after installing Ubuntu.

Then `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

This should make wireless connections work.

*Note: Bluetooth is also possible to configure, though it's harder, and there is not so much help out there (I did get bluetooth to work once)*

## Update

You can as well download the package here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/bcmwl-kernel-source

Though **make sure to select the right version**! The  link I've provided leads to the package for *jammy (22.04LTS)* and you might be on a different one. You can select it at the top of the page.

This is useful if you can only access internet from another device. After downloading – you can simply transfer the package using a USB flash drive or your phone and install it using `dpkg`. I.e.:

```
dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I used this tutorial to share Internet over Ethernet: https://crookm.com/journal/2018/sharing-wifi-connection-over-ethernet/

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04 despite several error messages during the install of "bcmwl-kernel-source".